# How do I return to a main menu on a ussd application in python?

Tags: python

here is my code:

#global variables are defined here:

menu_option = ["1. buy data", "2. top up", "3. exit"]

buy_data = ["1. N100 for 100mb", "2. N200 for 200mb", "0.back"]

top_up = ["1. self", "2. third party", "0.back"]

#I defined a function that allows user to input a ussd code and then return different telecom packages
#code runs perfectly, only that I dont know what to return to go back to  the menu options when menu == 0.

def ussd_app(code):

Here is a ussdcode lines for MTN telecommunication company:

```
if code == "*131#":
        print("Welcome to MTN!")
        print("Please, select a package")
        for item in menu_option:               
        print(item)
        menu = int(input("Select package: "))
        if menu == 1:
            for item in buy_data:
                print(item)
            buy_data_plan = int(input("Choose a plan: "))
            if buy_data_plan == 1:
                return f"You have selected\n\n{buy_data[0]}"
            elif buy_data_plan == 2:
                return f"You have selected\n\n{buy_data[1]}"
            elif buy_data_plan == 0:
                return 
            else:
                return f"Wrong input!"
        elif menu == 2:
            print("Select a top up plan!")
            for item in top_up:
                print(item)
            top_up_plan = int(input("Select a top up plan: "))
            if top_up_plan == 1:
                self_num = input("Enter your number: ")
                return f"Successfully credited airtime on {self_num}"
            elif top_up_plan == 2:
                third_party_num = input("Enter third party number: ")
                return f"Successfully credited airtime on {third_party_num}"
            elif top_up_plan == 0:
                return 
            else:
                return f"Wrong input!"
        elif menu == 3:
            return f"You have exit the USSD interface!"
```

#Another telecom ussd code
#codelines for Globacom telecommunication

```
    if code == "#124#":
        print("Welcome to GLOBACOM!")
        print("Please, select a package")
        for item in menu_option:
            print(item)
        menu = int(input("Select package: "))
        if menu == 1:
            for item in buy_data:
                print(item)
            buy_data_plan = int(input("Choose a plan: "))
            if buy_data_plan == 1:
                return f"You have selected\n\n{buy_data[0]}"
            elif buy_data_plan == 2:
                return f"You have selected\n\n{buy_data[1]}"
            else:
                return f"Wrong input!"
        elif menu == 2:
            print("Select a top up plan!")
            for item in top_up:
                print(item)
            top_up_plan = int(input("Select a top up plan: "))
            if top_up_plan == 1:
                self_num = input("Enter your number: ")
                return f"Successfully credited airtime on {self_num}"
            elif top_up_plan == 2:
                third_party_num = input("Enter third party number: ")
                return f"Successfully credited airtime on {third_party_num}"
            else:
                return f"Wrong input!"
        elif menu == 3:
            return f"You have exit the USSD interface!"
```

#Final telecom ussd code
#code lines for airtel communication

```
    if code == "#121#":
        print("Welcome to AIRTEL!")
        print("Please, select a package")
        for item in menu_option:
            print(item)
        menu = int(input("Select package: "))
        if menu == 1:
            for item in buy_data:
                print(item)
            buy_data_plan = int(input("Choose a plan: "))
            if buy_data_plan == 1:
                return f"You have selected\n\n{buy_data[0]}"
            elif buy_data_plan == 2:
                return f"You have selected\n\n{buy_data[1]}"
            else:
                return f"Wrong input!"
        elif menu == 2:
            print("Select a top up plan!")
            for item in top_up:
                print(item)
            top_up_plan = int(input("Select a top up plan: "))
            if top_up_plan == 1:
                self_num = input("Enter your number: ")
                return f"Successfully credited airtime on {self_num}"
            elif top_up_plan == 2:
                third_party_num = input("Enter third party number: ")
                return f"Successfully credited airtime on {third_party_num}"
            else:
                return f"Wrong input!"
       elif menu == 3:
           return f"You have exit the USSD interface!"
    else:
        return f"Wrong USSD code!"
```

print(ussd_app(input("Enter a code: ")))

Comment: What happened to your code formatting? Why there's `?

Comment: maybe put whole code  into a while(true) loop. then just use break/contine

Comment: I am so sorry about that. I will correct and post again.

Comment: what's this `main()` do anyway?

Comment: can you expatiate, pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
menu_option = ["1. buy data", "2. top up", "3. exit"]
buy_data = ["1. N100 for 100mb", "2. N200 for 200mb", "0.back"]
top_up = ["1. self", "2. third party", "0.back"]
```

#using while loop

```
def ussd_app(code):
       if code == "*131#":
            print("Welcome to MTN!")
            print("Please, select a package")
            while code == "*131#":
                for item in menu_option:
                   print(item)
                menu = int(input("Select package: "))
                if menu == 1:
                    for item in buy_data:
                       print(item)
                    buy_data_plan = int(input("Choose a plan: "))
                    if buy_data_plan == 1:
                        return f"You have selected\n\n{buy_data[0]}"
                    elif buy_data_plan == 2:
                        return f"You have selected\n\n{buy_data[1]}"
                    elif buy_data_plan == 0:
                        break
                    else:
                        return f"Wrong input!"
                elif menu == 2:
                     print("Select a top up plan!")
                     for item in top_up:
                         print(item)
                     top_up_plan = int(input("Select a top up plan: "))
                     if top_up_plan == 1:
                        self_num = input("Enter your number: ")
                        return f"Successfully credited airtime on {self_num}"
                     elif top_up_plan == 2:
                        third_party_num = input("Enter third party number: ")
                        return f"Successfully credited airtime on {third_party_num}"
                     elif top_up_plan == 0:
                          break
                     else:
                         return f"Wrong input!"
                elif menu == 3:
                     return f"You have exit the USSD interface!"

print(ussd_app(input("Enter USSD code: ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED (Using Nested While loop to go back to main menu):**

```
menu_option = ["1. buy data", "2. top up", "3. exit"]
buy_data = ["1. N100 for 100mb", "2. N200 for 200mb", "0.back"]
top_up = ["1. self", "2. third party", "0.back"]

def ussd_app(code):
    while True:
        if code == "*131#":
            print("Welcome to MTN!")
            print("Please, select a package")
            for item in menu_option:
                print(item)
            menu = int(input("Select package: "))
            if menu == 1:
                for item in buy_data:
                    print(item)
                while True:
                    buy_data_plan = int(input("Choose a plan: "))
                    if buy_data_plan == 1:
                        return f"You have selected\n\n{buy_data[0]}"
                    elif buy_data_plan == 2:
                        return f"You have selected\n\n{buy_data[1]}"
                    elif buy_data_plan == 0:
                        break
                    else:
                        print(f"Wrong input!")
            elif menu == 2:
                print("Select a top up plan!")
                for item in top_up:
                    print(item)
                while True:
                    top_up_plan = int(input("Select a top up plan: "))
                    if top_up_plan == 1:
                        self_num = input("Enter your number: ")
                        return f"Successfully credited airtime on {self_num}"
                    elif top_up_plan == 2:
                        third_party_num = input("Enter third party number: ")
                        return f"Successfully credited airtime on {third_party_num}"
                    elif top_up_plan == 0:
                        break
                    else:
                        print(f"Wrong input!")
            elif menu == 3:
                return f"You have exit the USSD interface!"

        elif code == "#124#":
            print("Welcome to GLOBACOM!")
            print("Please, select a package")
            for item in menu_option:
                print(item)
            menu = int(input("Select package: "))
            if menu == 1:
                for item in buy_data:
                    print(item)
                while True:
                    buy_data_plan = int(input("Choose a plan: "))
                    if buy_data_plan == 1:
                        return f"You have selected\n\n{buy_data[0]}"
                    elif buy_data_plan == 2:
                        return f"You have selected\n\n{buy_data[1]}"
                    elif buy_data_plan == 0:
                        break
                    else:
                        print(f"Wrong input!")
            elif menu == 2:
                print("Select a top up plan!")
                for item in top_up:
                    print(item)
                while True:
                    top_up_plan = int(input("Select a top up plan: "))
                    if top_up_plan == 1:
                        self_num = input("Enter your number: ")
                        return f"Successfully credited airtime on {self_num}"
                    elif top_up_plan == 2:
                        third_party_num = input("Enter third party number: ")
                        return f"Successfully credited airtime on {third_party_num}"
                    elif top_up_plan == 0:
                        break
                    else:
                        print(f"Wrong input!")
            elif menu == 3:
                return f"You have exit the USSD interface!"

        elif code == "#121#":
            print("Welcome to AIRTEL!")
            print("Please, select a package")
            for item in menu_option:
                print(item)
            menu = int(input("Select package: "))
            if menu == 1:
                for item in buy_data:
                    print(item)
                while True:
                    buy_data_plan = int(input("Choose a plan: "))
                    if buy_data_plan == 1:
                        return f"You have selected\n\n{buy_data[0]}"
                    elif buy_data_plan == 2:
                        return f"You have selected\n\n{buy_data[1]}"
                    elif buy_data_plan == 0:
                        break
                    else:
                        print(f"Wrong input!")
            elif menu == 2:
                print("Select a top up plan!")
                for item in top_up:
                    print(item)
                while True:
                    top_up_plan = int(input("Select a top up plan: "))
                    if top_up_plan == 1:
                        self_num = input("Enter your number: ")
                        return f"Successfully credited airtime on {self_num}"
                    elif top_up_plan == 2:
                        third_party_num = input("Enter third party number: ")
                        return f"Successfully credited airtime on {third_party_num}"
                    elif top_up_plan == 0:
                        break
                    else:
                        print(f"Wrong input!")
            elif menu == 3:
                return f"You have exit the USSD interface!"
        else:
            return f"Wrong USSD code!"

print(ussd_app(input("Enter a code: ")))
```

Comment: please, I still do not get it. The "return main()" was a mistake, I actually wanted to define a  main() function inside the function to return back to the main menu but it didn't work. my question is what do I get to return when "menu == 0", that is if a user wants to go back to menu after selecting a package.

Comment: Also, in the variables I defined above, which includes: "menu_option", "buy_data" and "top_up", I am trying to go back from buy data or top up back to menu option

Comment: Just as in this code, using infinite `while` loop. Change `return` statement in `else` block to `print`. And when it reach that condition, it'll print and back to beginning of `while` block which is code == input then display menu option

Comment: Well, you need to add another while loop (nested while loop) before input buy_data_plan and top_up_plan line

Comment: The code has beed updated, using nested while loop. It'll break the inner loop when input is 0. You can try it.

Comment: You can add another input after user selecting a package. From there you can select whether to menu option or calling the ussd_app function. By the way, return ends the function, you should define another function if you're not willing to use loop.

Comment: Thank you very much, bro. but I have tried out the code just now but it is still returning a none function after I input 0.

Comment: Ive tried to define another functions inside of it too but it didnt work .I will try it again

Comment: What do you mean by _it is still returning a none function after I input 0_? As in the code, input 0 will not returning anything. It'll break the loop and back to menu option as well as go back to buy_data_plan and top_up_plan.

Comment: Thank you... I've been able to solve it with while loop and nested functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
menu_option = ["1. buy data", "2. top up", "3. exit"]
buy_data = ["1. N100 for 100mb", "2. N200 for 200mb", "0.back"]
top_up = ["1. self", "2. third party", "0.back"]
```

#Using nested funtions

```
def ussd_app(code):
    if code == "*131#":
        print("Welcome to MTN!")
        print("Please, select a package")
    elif code == "#124#":
        print("Welcome to GLOBACOM!")
        print("Please, select a package")
    elif code == "*121#":
        print("Welcome to AIRTEL!")
        print("Please, select a package")
    else:
        return f"Wrong USSD code!"

    def main():
        if code == "*131#":
            for item in menu_option:
                print(item)
            menu = int(input("Select package: "))
            if menu == 1:
                for item in buy_data:
                    print(item)
                buy_data_plan = int(input("Choose a plan: "))
                if buy_data_plan == 1:
                    return f"You have selected\n\n{buy_data[0]}"
                elif buy_data_plan == 2:
                    return f"You have selected\n\n{buy_data[1]}"
                elif buy_data_plan == 0:
                    return main()
                else:
                    return f"Wrong input!"
            elif menu == 2:
                print("Select a top up plan!")
                for item in top_up:
                    print(item)
                top_up_plan = int(input("Select a top up plan: "))
                if top_up_plan == 1:
                    self_num = input("Enter your number: ")
                    return f"Successfully credited airtime on {self_num}"
                elif top_up_plan == 2:
                    third_party_num = input("Enter third party number: ")
                    return f"Successfully credited airtime on {third_party_num}"
                elif top_up_plan == 0:
                    return main()
                else:
                    return f"Wrong input!"
            else:
                return f"You have exit the USSD interface!"
    
    return main()

print(ussd_app(input("Enter USSD code: ")))
```